# Why is valgrind limited to 32 Gb on 64 bit architectures?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, 64-bit, valgrind

I'm trying to valgrind a heisenbug on a process which uses more than 32 Gb of ram and hitting this valgrind limitation, is this an arbitrary one that could be avoided by recompiling valgrind or is it a hard one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit is arbitrary and can be changed by recompiling valgrind.

Valgrind keeps track of memory using a 2-level sparse array.  16 bits of the address are used to index into a 65536-entry table containing a pointer to a second-level map, which tracks a range of the address space (normally 2¹⁶ bytes = 64KB for 32-bit processes, 2¹⁹ bytes = 512KB for 64-bit processes).  So the total amount of memory that can be tracked by this 2-level sparse array is 65536 × this chunk size.  By modifying the code, the size of these chunks can be increased to a larger power of 2, at the cost of using more memory to track most partial chunks.

In [this message](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27779126) on the valgrind-users mailing list, Julian Seward explains how to increase the limit from 32GB to 128GB:

> - in `memcheck/mc_main.c` change `N_PRIMARY_BITS` from `19` to `21`
> - change the assertions at the end of `memcheck/mc_main.c` accordingly:
>
>   - `MAX_PRIMARY_ADDRESS` →  4 * (existing value + 1) - 1
>   - for the `MASK(1/2/4/8)` assertions, set to zero the rightmost two
>       '1' bits in the block of leading 1 bits, eg
>       `MASK(8)` → `0xFFFFFFE000000007ULL`  I think
> - in `coregrind/m_aspacemgr/aspacemgr-linux.c` change `aspacem_maxAddr` from
>     `(Addr)0x800000000 - 1` to `(Addr)0x2000000000ULL - 1`.

---

**Update:**
The maximum amount of memory that Valgrind can use has increased in recent versions:

- 32 GB prior to Valgrind 3.9
- 64 GB in Valgrind 3.9 through 3.12
- 128 GB in Valgrind 3.13